# How to get the Drupal webform submission changed value?

Tags: hooks, webforms

I'm trying to get the webform submission changed data when a form submission is updated in date format to be captured into a custom field.
I'm able to get the webform completed value in a custom submission handler as below,
`$custom_date = $webform_submission->getData();`
`$completed_date = $webform_submission->completed->value;`

Also the below does not print the date format with am/pm.
strtotime(date('DD/MM/Y g:i:s'))

How do I get the webform submission changed value in date format with am/pm?

Comment: It 's bit difficult to provide ans without knowing in which hook you are trying to get changed value and what actual flow you are following like creating webform etc, try to elaborate these things

Answer (score 1):

To get webform submission data and manipulate it before the save you can use a `presave` hook. Hooks must be declared inside a `.module` file at the root of a custom module.

Here's an example for your use case :

```php
<?php

use Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave() for webform_submission.
 */
function my_module_webform_submission_presave(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
  if ($webform_submission->getWebform()->id() != 'my_webform') {
    return;
  }
  // Webform data.
  $data = $webform_submission->getData();
  // Webform date field value is a string in Y-m-d H:i:s format.
  $value = $data['datetime'];
  // Feel free to transform it in any format you want.
  $datetime = new DateTime($value);
  // Like AM/PM as you need :
  $am_pm = $datetime->format('Y-m-d  H:i A');// 2023-10-27 07:29 AM
  // And then save it in your custom field.
  $data['custom_field'] = $am_pm;
  // And set the current Webform with new data.
  $webform_submission->setData($data);
}
```

> Note that, to manipulate Webform data it's recommended to use a **Webform handler**. You can find a lot of resources on the World Wide Web explaining that : [How to create a drupal webform handler ?](https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=how+to+create+a+drupal+webform+handler+%3F)